# Structure Howler.js script for playback just like this SoundManager2 example code?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, howler.js

[**In this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378645/trying-to-play-audio-using-javascript-but-is-not-playing) you can find SoundManager2 and Howler.js code examples for audio playback.

I basically use the SoundManager2 script from that page - with a few modifications as shown in the code snippet below.

In my HTML5 browser app I could use this script to simply play a sound by calling the sound id("Song1") and the function("playAudio" for example).

**My question:**
How can I structure a Howler.js script to get the same functionality
 → play a sound by calling the sound id and the correct function?

[Howler.js Documentation](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="api/soundmanager2.js"></script>
    <script>
        soundManager.setup({
     url: 'api/',
     onready: function() {

    soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'Song1',
      url: 'audio/Song1.ogg'
        });
      },
    });
    function playAudio(snd) {
        soundManager.play(snd);
    }
    function stopAudio(snd) {
        soundManager.stop(snd);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Howler.js is meant to be a simple API, so it doesn't have this feature built-in, but it would be easy enough to just create a map with an object:

```js
var Song1 = new Howl({
  src: 'audio/Song1.ogg'
});
var Song2 = new Howl({
  src: 'audio/Song2.ogg'
});

var sounds = {
  Song1: Song1,
  Song2: Song2,
};

function playAudio(snd) {
  sounds[snd].play();
}

function stopAudio(snd) {
  sounds[snd].stop();
}
```